# LinQ Accessing A Mutual Item for Comparison

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to express this, So any Edits would be Appreciated

The Idea

I have list A and List B

I need to go See If List A's Item's ID is the same as List B's ID

So I can Check to see if List A's Status is = To Something So That If that's the case I can Not Show The Item Or even delete the item From list B

Here's what I tried:

```
                        foreach (var Itemz in _items.FlashItems)
                        {

                            foreach (var item in p)
                            {
                                if (Itemz.PId == item.id && item.status != "publish")
                                {
                                    //Remove Drafted Products ECT

                                    await DisplayAlert("Sale Over!", $"Sorry the Sale for 
                                    {item.Name} has ended, Removing Item from you cart", "Ok");

                                   Itemz.status = item.status;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Then I can go And say

```
  cartView.ItemsSource = _items.FlashItems.Where(z => z.status == "publish").ToList();
```

Is there a better way to do this? This doesn't seem like a very Acceptable way of doing this.

Comment: So... what is your actual question? What is not working as expected? Do you get any errors?

Comment: My bad actually forgot to ask the question. It feels Very "Scuffed" I'm wondering if theres a better way, Aslo I'm essentially iterating of p far more then I feel I have to. Which can slow down everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LinQ Join, and Value Tuples:

```
var myItems = _items.FlashItems
  .Join(p.Where(i => i.status != "publish"),
    f => f.PId,
    i => i.id,
    (f, i) => (f, i));

foreach ((FlashItemsClass f, ItemsClass i) in myItems)
{
  f.status = i.status;

  await DisplayAlert("Sale Over!", $"Sorry the Sale for {i.Name} has ended, Removing Item from you cart", "Ok");
}
```

Comment: Awesome, So I'm guessing by saying ,(f, i) => (f, i)); Your basically saying if(f = i) ?

Comment: 4-th parameter to [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__) is select statement so first (f, i) menas from element pair from first and second colection, and second is [value tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8) declaration, so (f, i) means create new value tuple from elements f and i.

Comment: Comparision in join is between second and third parameter, so `(..., f => f.PId,
    i => i.id, ...)` means that if f.PId from first collection == i.id from second collection, then do join.